# elimine modulo y no me aaprece android en las opciones

Tags: configuración

Trataba de solucionar un problema con el gradle respecto a un modulo (Toasty de GitHub)
y sin quere me parece que borre los módulos
ahora ya no me aparece la opción de "android" en el menu de proyecto.

como puedo solucionar al para poder ejecutar la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya no me aparece la opción android...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos.java , layout y otros recursos del proyecto me siguen apareciendo pero no logro ejecutar la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al tratar de compilar me aparece tambien que no hay modelos  y modelos no especificado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que mensaje te sale al compilar? seria bueno que compartas el error. Me parece que es por la version del gradle que no tienes instalado. Prueba esto (desde el paso 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42190851

Comment: Hola, gracias, el error que me aparece es que no hay modulo especificado <no modulo> (adjunté una imagen de eso en la publicación al final)

Comment: haz cualquier cambio en el archivo `app/build.gradle`  (ej. cambia el applicationId), luego dale en 'sync Now' y publica el error que te sale. Tambien seria bueno que publiques tu archivo `app/build.gradle`